# Email not received from email alerts

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, automation

Hi all I am trying to receive an email each time I create a new grant with a particular record type a particular organization name linked etc. Few conditions.
[image]

So I have created an email template according to my format and I have added it an email alert and called it to my flow as an apex action.
When I test it by creating a new grant record the conditions in the update record is happening but I am not receiving an email to the email id I provided in the email alert.I checked and changed the Delivaribility to all emails from system emails.Is it the issue related to the org or an issue in my flow..Should I provide a condition to check if the value is updated after the updated records and only then sent the email.But that isn't necessary right?I am getting the updated values after creation.

[image]

Debug results

Comment: a very minor check would be to check the logged in user email address is valid email address or not. If this does not help, generate the email audit log file and review what's going wrong.

Comment: Did you try to debug the flow and see if it is receiving to that element or failing at any part of the floe?

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala I have added the debug results.

Comment: @sanketkumar But I will have to request the email logs right?

Comment: @JK123, Yes you need to raise a email log request and check the log file

Comment: @JK123, Just try removing all the merge fields in the template and just give some text for testing and check if that is because of template issue. Because I dont see any issue with the flow.

Comment: You can check whther mails are sent from Salesforce, Go to your email template and there you have an option to send and test that email template... Or in Quick Find you can type "Test Deliverability" where you have the option to send a test email from SF. If no emails are sent you might have to enable it, Find "Deliverability" in Quick Find Box and set Access Level to "All Email".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi As PraveenKumar you have to check the deliverability to all email,but I see that you have mentioned in the question that you have changed it.Then the possible issue can be found through debugging.But there is no issues in your flow as far as I can understand.Check thoroghly through your email alerts and check the mails provided.Also please check your spam mails as well..Such messages may end up there
Thanks